# How this particular Collection is suitable for the particular scenario?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I was reading some sample question from Enthuware exam simulator. I came across a question whose
problem statement is like this

> You are designing a class that will cache objects. It should be able
>   to store and retrieve an object when supplied with an object
>   identifier. Further, this class should work by tracking the "last
>   accessed times" of the objects. Thus, if its capacity is full, it
>   should remove only the object that hasn't been accessed the longest.
>
> Which collection class would you use to store the objects?

The possible options given were

1. HashSet
2. ArrayList
3. LinkedHashMap
4. LinkedList
5. TreeMap

The correct answer given by simulator is LinkedHashMap. I would quote the explanation
given by simulator.

> The LinkedHashMap class maintains the elements in the order of their
>   insertion time. This property can be used to build the required cache
>   as follows:
>
> 1. Insert the key-value pairs as you do normally where key will be the object identifier and value will be the object to be cached.
> 2. When a key is requested, remove it from the LinkedHashMap and then insert it again. This will make sure that this pair marked as inserted
>      latest.
> 3. If the capacity is full, remove the first element.
>
> Note that you cannot simply insert the key-value again (without first
>   removing it) because a reinsertion operation does not affect the
>   position of the pair.

I do understand the first point only. Still here are the following questions.

1. In point-1 it states, the value will be the object to be cached? How does caching apply like this?
2. I am not able to understand from point-2 onwards.

Can someone explain this concept to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should take the 'caching' from the example with a grain of salt: it's meant to provide some context, but not entirely relevant.

The caching here is likely meant as retrieving a value from the collection instead of accessing a data source and get it from there.

As to your second question:

> When a key is requested, remove it from the LinkedHashMap and then
>   insert it again. This will make sure that this pair marked as inserted
>   latest.

Consider the following Map:

> ID | Value
>   1  | Jack
>   5  | John
>   3  | Jenny

In this situation `Jack` was entered first, then `John` and after that `Jenny`.
Now we want to retrieve the cached value of `John`. If we want to do so, we first retrieve the value for his unique identifier (`5`) and we get the object `John` as result. Right now we have our cached value, but the requirement to track the last access time hasn't been fullfilled yet. Therefore we delete him and add him again, essentially placing him at the end.

> ID | Value
>   1  | Jack
>   3  | Jenny
>   5  | John

John stays cached, but now his access time has been updated. Whenever the map is full, you remove the first item in line (which will essentially be the item that's not been accessed for the longest time).

If the map has a maximum size of `3` and we try to add `Jeff`, we get the following situation:

> ID | Value
>   3  | Jenny
>   5  | John
>   7  | Jeff

The first item (`Jack`) and thus the least-recently accessed object will be removed, making place for the new object (most-recently accessed).

Comment: I was about to write an answer, then realized I got confused myself. good explanation.

Comment: @Jeroen, perfect answer. Thank you so much for helping me with an example to explain the concept. I am very thankful. Perfect explanation.

Answer (score 2):

> In point-1 it states, the value will be the object to be cached? How does caching apply like this?

Caching an object here means storing the created objects, in some collections, so that they can be retrieved later. Now as the requirement is to store and retrieve objects using it's key, clearly a `Map` is the option here, which will store the mapping from object's `Key` to the `object` itself.

Also, `LinkedHashMap` is suitable, because it maintains the insertion order. So, the first object you create, will be the first in the that map.

> When a key is requested, remove it from the LinkedHashMap and then insert it again. This will make sure that this pair marked as inserted latest.

Again, take a look at the requirement. It says, the elements that haven't be accessed for long, should be removed. Now suppose an object which is at the first position, hasn't been accessed for long. So, when you access it now, you wouldn't want to be still in the first position, because in that case, when you remove the first elements, you will be removing the elements you just accessed.

That is why you should remove the element, and insert it back, so that it is placed at the end.

> If the capacity is full, remove the first element.

As it's already clear, the first element is the one, which was inserted first, and has the oldest access time. So, you should remove the first element only, as the requirement says:

> if its capacity is full, it should remove only the object that hasn't been accessed the longest.

Comment: thank you so much. Your answers are always commendable and easy to follow. Thankyou so very much.

Answer (score 2):

First step, determine if you need a Set, Map, or List.

1. Lists preserve order.
2. Maps allow fast, key based, look up of items.
3. Sets provide identity based membership, in other words, no duplicates.

You probably want lookup by key, so It's some sort of map.  However, you also want to preserve order.  At first glance, LinkedHashMap seems a winner, but it is not.

LinkedHashMap preserves insertion order, and you want to preserve access order.  To twist one into another, you would have to remove and add back each element as it is accessed.  This is very wasteful, and subject to timing issues (between the would-be-atomic add and read).

You could simplify both by maintaining two internal data structures.

1. A HashMap for fast access.
2. A linked list to quickly reorder based on access times.

As you insert, the hashmap stores a linked list node, who's key is the key for the stored data object within the linked list node.  The node is added on the "newer" end of the list.

As you access, the hashmap pulls up the linked list node, which is then removed and inserted into the head of the linked list. (and the data is returned).

As you delete, the hashmap pulls up the linked list node, and removes it from the linked list, and clears the hashmap entry.

When removing a expired entry, remove from the old end of the linked list, and don't forget to clear out the hashmap entry.

By doing this, you have built your own kind of LinkedHashMap, but one that tracks according to access time instead of insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

They are omitting three very important points:

1. Together with the `LinkedHashMap`, a mechanism to determine when to start removing objects is necessary.  The most simple one is a counter `availableCapacity` initialized to the maximum capacity and decremented/incremented accordingly.  An alternative is to compare the `size()` of the `LinkedHashMap` with a `maximumCapacity` variable.
2. The `LinkedHashMap` (specifically its `values()`) is assumed to contain the only pointers to the cached objects/structures.  If any other pointers are kept, they are assumed to be transient.
3. The cache is to be administered under a LRU regime.

This said, and to answer your questions:

1. Yes.
2. By definition, the `first` item in a LinkedHashMap is the first inserted ("oldest").  If every time a cache entry is used it is removed and re-inserted into the map, it is placed at the end of the list and thus made the "newest".  `first` will always be the one that has **not** been used for the longest time.  "second" the following, and so on.  This is why the elements from the front are removed.

Comment: @benz  LRU= "Least Recently Used" .  IOW, the LRU items are removed to make room for the ones more recently used.  In particular, for the one **just** used.  This regime works well when access probability doesn't change with time.  The opposite regime (MRU) works well when it's highly improbable that the same item is used twice in a row.  This is very rare, but can happen in cases of cyclic access.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedHashMap stores items in the order they were inserted. They're using one to implement an LRU cache. The keys are the object identifiers. The values are the items to be cached. Maps have a very fast lookup time, which is what makes the map a cache. It's faster to do the lookup than to

Inserting items into the map puts them at the end of the map. So every time you read something, you take it out and put it back on the end. Then, when you need more room in your cache, you chop off the first element. That's the one that hasn't been used in the longest time, because it made its way all the way to the front.